# How can I change this code to handle recurringpayment?

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to implement Direct payment method as I have user's credit card information etc in my database. This is the sample that I am referring:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
using com.paypal.soap.api;

namespace ASPDotNetSamples
{
    public class DoDirectPayment
    {
        public DoDirectPayment()
        {
        }
        public string DoDirectPaymentCode(string paymentAction, string amount, string creditCardType, string creditCardNumber, string expdate_month, string cvv2Number, string firstName, string lastName, string address1, string city, string state, string zip, string countryCode, string currencyCode)
        {

            com.paypal.soap.api.DoDirectPaymentReq req = new com.paypal.soap.api.DoDirectPaymentReq();


            NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
            IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
            /*
             WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
             Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
             Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
             encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
             that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
             */

            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, API operation and version.
            profile.APIUsername = "sdk-three_api1.sdk.com";
            profile.APIPassword = "QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q";
            profile.APISignature = "AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ";
            profile.Environment = "sandbox";
            caller.APIProfile = profile;

            NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
            encoder["VERSION"] = "51.0";
            encoder["METHOD"] = "DoDirectPayment";

            // Add request-specific fields to the request.
            encoder["PAYMENTACTION"] = paymentAction;
            encoder["AMT"] = amount;
            encoder["CREDITCARDTYPE"] = creditCardType;
            encoder["ACCT"] = creditCardNumber;
            encoder["EXPDATE"] = expdate_month;
            encoder["CVV2"] = cvv2Number;
            encoder["FIRSTNAME"] = firstName;
            encoder["LASTNAME"] = lastName;
            encoder["STREET"] = address1;
            encoder["CITY"] = city;
            encoder["STATE"] = state;
            encoder["ZIP"] = zip;
            encoder["COUNTRYCODE"] = countryCode;
            encoder["CURRENCYCODE"] = currencyCode;

            // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
            string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
            string pStresponsenvp = caller.Call(pStrrequestforNvp);

            NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
            decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
            return decoder["ACK"];

        }
    }
}
```

This is the link:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_DoDirectPayment_cs.txt

This works fine but my only question is how do I handle recurringpayment with this? What changes should I make in the sample?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you have their credit card details, why not just call your routine every month?? (Or whatever frequency...)

Comment: That is a good idea. However, it requires me to create windows service or any such application on my own end and deal with threads etc. What if my threads miss to run at appropriate time. Payment is a critical functionality and I don't want to screw it up. Rather than that I think it would be advisable to just delegate this process of to Paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [PayPal API Reference.](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference)

There is a method named `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`

Also read [Handling Recurring Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments)